# Eclipse Kepler XML validation

Tags: xml, eclipse, validation, xsd

I'm using:

- Eclispe Kepler Service Release 2 on Windows 7
- Rinzo Xml Editor Core 1.4
- Rinzo Xml Java integration 1.4

I've created a new project (File->New Project...) and added two files to it (New->File):

cd.xsd and cd-istance.xml. These files are in the same project (folder).

I don't have any menu like New->XML ... 
I'm not able to validate the xml istance of the xsd neither while writing the xml nor when the xml is done (There is no Preference->Validate option or something similar).

Actually, I don't know if the reference to my xsd is correct or if Eclipse does not work properly.

Hereafter the cd.xsd.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
xmlns:xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
elementFormDefault = "qualified"
>

<xs:simpleType name = "artist" >
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:length value= "5">
        </xs:length>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>    
<xs:element name = "title" type = "xs:string"></xs:element>
<xs:element name = "year" type = "xs:gYear"></xs:element>

<xs:element name = "song" >
    <xs:complexType name = "songType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="artist" minOccur="0"></xs:element>
            <xs:element ref="title" minOccur="0" maxOccur="1"></xs:element>
            <xs:element ref="year" maxOccur="1"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Hereafter the cd-istance.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="UTF-8"?>
<CD
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamSpaceSchemaLocation="cd.xsd" 
>
   <artist>  </artist>
   <title> la  prova</title>
   <title> la prova2 </title>
</CD>
```

I'm expecting at least two errors, one for artist (which is empty) and another for title (which violates the constraints on the occurrence).

I've done a number of attempts, just to mention some:

- Added `xsi:noNamSpaceSchemaLocation="./cd.xsd"`
- Added `xsi:targetLocation="./cd.xsd"` ("cd.xsd") and added `targetNameSpace="www.mynamespace.com"` (it is a fake address)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the `xsi:noNameSpaceSchemaLocation` attribute that binds the schema to the file. Your file header should be:

```
<CD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNameSpaceSchemaLocation="cd.xsd"> ...
```

If you are still having trouble validating in your environment, you can use an online service such as [this one](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation).

I pasted your instance and XSD and made some changes for it to validate. I saved the link in a [fiddle](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=977f0bd0-8345-454f-8c49-53f7d9daf053-xsdvalidation#.U3DY361dVtM).

The problems in your XSD are:

1. Your XML Schema is not well-formed. Add an `</xs:schema>` tag at the end.
2. There is no `CD` element declared. Replace `<xs:element name="song">` with `<xs:element name="CD">`.
3. `maxOccurs` and `minOccurs` attributes are misspelled in several places.
4. You have a nested named `complexType` in the `song` element definition. If you have a nested `complexType` it should not have a `name`. Either make it top-level or remove the `name` attribute.
5. There is no **element** named `artist`. There is, however, a *type* with that name. You can either nest the `simpleType` inside an `<xs:element name="artist">` declaration (and remove the `name` attribute from the type), or keep the type as top-level and declare an `<xs:element name="artist" type="artist">` that refers to it (you might want to use different names for the types and elements to avoid confusion):

```xml
<xs:element name="artist" type="ArtistType" />
    <xs:simpleType name="ArtistType" >
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:length value="5"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Once those problems are fixed, you will have validation errors:

1. There are not exactly 5 characters in your `<artist>` element
2. There is more than one `<title>` element (at most one is allowed by the schema)
3. There is not a required `<year>` element containing a valid `xs:gYear` type following the `<title>`

You code is validated [here](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=977f0bd0-8345-454f-8c49-53f7d9daf053-xsdvalidation#.U3DY361dVtM). You can make changes and see the validation results.

Comment: A random downvote? It would be nice to know the reason. Any dead links?